# facebook credits

Tags: facebook

**EDIT 1:**

Is it possible to withdraw facebook credits your facebook application has received?  So the received credits can go into your real bank account?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

Is it possible to use facebook users credits to pay for items in a facebook app?  If it is possible, can someone please provide a link?  Also, how does it work i.e. for 10 facebook credits you have to pay £0.16 or something, and if they pay for an item in a facebook app which costs 10 facebook credits, does that mean the owner of the app gets £0.16?  Also, is the owner of the app able to widthdraw this money to his back account.  If yes, how much does the whole transaction cost the facebook app developer?

Comment: I would expect it is possible to get paid. Otherwise, there is no point for devs to use the facebook credit system - everything may as well be free

Comment: That is what I think also, but I can't seem to get this confirmed in the documentation, also I see no such option in my standard facebook account in the payments section.  The payments section just allows you to add money to your facebook account, but I see no option to withdraw credits from facebook to your bank account.

Comment: i have a related question as well please replay http://stackoverflow.com/q/7805388/958414

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***UPDATE 2***

as Kurru rightly points out in his answer, facebook credits *can* be redeemed to *developers* (just not to *users*). the [Facebook Credits Terms](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/credits/) says so, but in a quite convoluted way. better information can be found at [Facebook Credits for Developers](https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=1161), incl.

- How can I get started with Facebook Credits?
- How much can I redeem a Facebook Credit for?
- What payment options do Facebook Credits support?
- What is the process to ensure timely payout for an app that integrates Facebook Credits, as well as additional apps by the same company?
- Which countries can Facebook Credits currently pay out?".

***UPDATE 2 END***

***UPDATE***

https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/FacebookCreditsIntegrationGuidev1.pdf , p. 14:

> To build user trust, please follow both the [Facebook Credits Terms](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/credits/) and [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/), including (but not limited to) the following:
>
> Facebook Credits cannot be..
>
> 1. cashed out into real-world currency
> 2. used to enable person-to-person funds
> 3. used to sell physical or real-world items

Details (*Eligibility, (allowed) Transactions, Redemption, Actions We May Take, Transaction-Related Disputes, Other Terms*) are in the [Facebook Credits Terms](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/credits/).

***UPDATE END***

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/creditsapi/ :

> The Facebook Credits API enables a user to use credits as a method for purchasing digital and virtual goods within a Facebook canvas application. Please note: the credits api is not yet available for use by external websites but only on canvas iframe applications.

Comment: I was just reading the same documentation, but couldn't find anything which suggested that it is possible to transfer received facebook credits to your bank account.

Comment: Facebook credits can be cashed out, or else no devs would use them. They just cant be cashed out to users.

Comment: @Kurru yes, found this out also. will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Which means: as a developer you can sell virtual goods in your Facebook game. But you can not write a Poker game, where everyone could withdraw the winnings.

Answer (score 2):

As the developer you can get paid as detailed here : https://developers.facebook.com/policy/credits/

> **3.1**
>
> When you redeem Credits with us we will redeem them at the rate of
>   $0.10 per Credit, less a service fee
>   of $0.03 per credit redeemed. If we
>   change the service fee or redemption
>   rate, the redemption rate and service
>   fee in effect at the time you accepted
>   a Credit as consideration will apply
>   to that Credit. We will give you 30
>   days notice on the Facebook Developer
>   Website of changes to the redemption
>   rate or service fee.

Sounds like they basically take a 30% cut off the top. This can't be used to enable money transfers as specified by the previous answer.