# developing Facebook paid application without fb credits?

Tags: javascript, paypal, facebook-apps, facebook-credits

is it possible to create my **FB app** in **Fb iframe** and on pay button it **directs** to **Paypal** for payment and returns back to my fb app for further processing **without using Fb credits ?**

In **Facebook payment terms and policies** i have read:

NOTE: **Per the Facebook Credits Terms, all games on the Facebook Platform (including mobile web apps) must exclusively process payments through Facebook Credits.**

Plus if you know any app on FB using payment method without FB credits please specify the names of the apps . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What part of

> **All games** on the Facebook Platform (including mobile web apps) **must *exclusively* process payments through Facebook Credits**

is unclear to you?

Comment: no it is clear but i haven't found a single example of it yet that just let the user pay through PayPal . even the Astrology app on Fb uses tokes as FB credits to let teh use pay for compatibility with other firends.

and i want to ask a silly question but just for being sure, Who gets to decide its a game or app? me or FB?

Comment: @vzwick have got a link to your answer?, Im interested to know more.

Comment: @david [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/migration/) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/credits/)

Comment: @vzwick cheers!, sounds like there building there own economy.

Comment: thanks for the link but my question is still there .......who gets to decide its an app or game ? i don't want to lose my clinet's trust by just developing the paid application without credits and on later stage fb getsto say "Please implement credits"

Answer (score 1):

If the Facebook terms of use say you have to use facebook credits i don't think your app will be enabled if you don't respect that rule.

so even if it might be possible to use paypal directly, it will be a lot of work for nothing.